# Half Image display from url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

[image]

Hi,

i Asynchronous load image from url, problem is that image just load half i am not getting why this happening ,after some search on net i get two three reason for that,

**1 it may happen because of sever side problem.**

**2 it may happen because of image formate (but its happening for both the formate(png & jpg) so i thing that is not issue).**

**3 it may happen because of too large size of image (size of images between 200kb to 700kb)**

its also happening  in browser but sometimes.

if you have any solution or advise regarding this issue than plz replay.

Comment: Can you load asynchronously?

Comment: yes i am loading images asynchronously

Comment: In your question you said you are loading synchronously, not asynchronously.

Comment: Since you say it's happening in the browser as well, it makes me think this is a server side error/problem.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you're loading this image in a uiwebview ?

Comment: no i am loading images in uiimageview

Comment: check my answer below - dilip.ajm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also facing these types of problem, it is basically the error of network when the asyncronous thread not able to download the image completely. The solution is to check whether downloaded image is valid or not. if not valid then download again. Below is the method i used to check whether image is valid or not:

Note: this check is only for PNG images, To check JPEG just replace first and last two bytes in "if" condition.

```
- (BOOL)isImageValid:(NSData *)data
{
    BOOL val = YES;

    if ([data length] < 4) 
        val = NO;

    const unsigned char * bytes = (const unsigned char *)[data bytes];

    if (bytes[0] != 0x89 || bytes[1] != 0x50) 
        val = NO;
    if (bytes[[data length] - 2] != 0x60 || 
        bytes[[data length] - 1] != 0x82) 
        val = NO;

    return val; //return YES if valid 
}
```

Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: yes i try  this before but its showing me all the my image is not valid

Comment: Of which format of images you are downloading? jpg or png? This method is working for me.

Comment: Create two methods to check jpg or png images separately. one for check png and other for jpg image.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.. It may be useful for you

```
 NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                  @"<html>"
                  "<head>"
                  "<script type=\"text/javascript\" >"
                  "function display(img){"
                  "var imgOrigH = document.getElementById('image').offsetHeight;"
                  "var imgOrigW = document.getElementById('image').offsetWidth;"
                  "var bodyH = window.innerHeight;"
                  "var bodyW = window.innerWidth;"
                  "if((imgOrigW/imgOrigH) > (bodyW/bodyH))"
                  "{"
                  "document.getElementById('image').style.width = bodyW + 'px';"
                  "document.getElementById('image').style.top = (bodyH - document.getElementById('image').offsetHeight)/2  + 'px';"
                  "}"
                  "else"
                  "{"
                  "document.getElementById('image').style.height = bodyH + 'px';"
                  "document.getElementById('image').style.marginLeft = (bodyW - document.getElementById('image').offsetWidth)/2  + 'px';"
                  "}"
                  "}"
                  "</script>"
                  "</head>"
                  "<body style=\"margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;\" >"
                  "<img id=\"image\" src=\"%@\" onload=\"display()\" style=\"position:relative\" />"
                  "</body>"
                  "</html>",pass your url string here];
```

Comment: but i want to cache images is it possible with uiwebview?

Comment: @SmartWork, I don't know it is possible or not.. but it will display your image completely in webview